# websphere and apache server proxy and rewrite configuration

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, proxy, websphere

There are javaEE applications run on WebSphere server.

The thing I wanna do that to configure a http server that takes the request and redirect to my local websphere server.

For example: 
This is live Project testProject.com/Otel..
I wanna reach my local project when I insert local.testProject.com/Otel..

The thing I have done so far I can reach my local apache server when I click local.testProject.com just with adding in host file in windows/system32/drivre/etc directory.

The thing I could not do so far. redirecting this incoming request to my apache server to websphere server.

Could you please help me on these. Dont hasitate to ask further questions.
I would be appreciated if you could give me some ideas with just commenting at least.

Good days..

Answer (score 0):

IBM provides a specialty reverse proxy module for Apache called the WebSphere WebServer Plug-in. Its use is described in detail in the websphere documentation.

In simple configurations, you can just configure any server you already have as a reverse proxy.

- Load mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http (varies depending on Apache distribution)
- Append to your virtual host:

  - ProxyPreserveHost ON
  - ProxyPass /otel http://washostname.example.com/otel
  - # ProxyPassReverse likely not required in your case.

Of course there are thousands of places to read about setting up Apache as a reverse proxy and there are nearly no WebSphere specifics.

Comment: Apache +IBM http plugin is just called IHS, IBM Http Server that you install alongside Websphere.

Comment: No, IBM's distribution of Apache is called IHS. The separately installable WebSphere WebServer Plug-in is called just that, and you can use it non-IHS Apache or other wbservers.